# C# API MySql Connection Multiple Errors

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

basicly I try to establish a simple MySQL Connection which I've done hundred of times already. But this time I dont know what I do wrong.
I'm using Visual Studio to build an API right now.

My general aproach to connect to a database is the following:

Add MySql.Data through NuGet.

Then connect using the following:

```
protected string myConnectionString = "server=[ip];uid=[uname];" +
        "pwd=[passwd];database=[db];";
protected MySqlCommand cmd = null;
protected MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
protected MySqlDataReader reader = null;
protected DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
protected void getData()
{

    try
    {
        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM rechner";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        conn.Open();
        // Load into a dataTable for multiple Access
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, myConnectionString);
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        conn.Close();           
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //Do Something
        }
```

Follow up with a catch block and so on.

But today is different. First it won't recognise MySqlDataAdapter on MySql.Data version 6.10.4. Which was odd. Then I downgraded to 6.9.10. Now it recognises MySqlDataAdapter but wont establish a connection. Everytime it says:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you go to the bin folder of your project, can you see there the assembly that the error message says that cannot be loaded? If so, try to clean your solution/project (right click on solution/project and click at clean) and give it a go again.

Comment: To add to Christos' comment, I occasionally have to just manually (in file explorer) delete the contents of my bin and Ctrl+Shift+B build my solution again. Can't say why, but often it works for me.

Comment: Sorry but that didnt help. I even created a whole new Project and still the same FileNotFoundException... weird.